# Not able to set multiple IStatus messages in IValidationContext Eclipse EMF

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

I am using EMF validation framework and need to validate two variables in the same validator class. I am not able to set 2 error messages in the IValidationContext object i.e.,
I tried:

```
IValidationContext ctx;
ctx.createFailureMessage(new String[]{a,b});
```

This did not work.  I also tried setting a list of `IStatus` in `ctx.createFailureMessage().` This also doesn't work.

Is it not possible to add multiple failure messages in the same validation context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a `MultiStatus` containing all the status messages in the `createFailureStatus` method